# Assuming secure code practices are adhered to, is a thousand-tier/n-tier microservices application or a monolithic application more secure?

Tags: microservices

Assuming secure code practices are all adhered to for both applications, is a thousand-tier/n-tier microservices application or a monolithic application more secure?

From a monitoring, visibility standpoint, etc. I am trying to understand which paradigm is a more secure paradigm.

Comment: This is close to *is a red car or a green car more fast?* Microservice is a nice tool for structuring a large application in smaller blocks. But nothing prevents to structure a monolithic application in multiple layers and blocs, each having a single responsability zone. In the end both application would have the same maintainability level. Said differently micro-services is one possible tool, but nothing more. What matters is the way the applications was designed, not the tool.

Comment: The question is too broad. That's why I suggest to close it.

Comment: Please stop signing your posts. Your profile banner is your signature